# Areas inside a Quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

I got a question, and have been unable to solve it. I asked a lot of people, but no one can answer.

> Let there be a Quadrilateral $ABCD$. $M$ and $N$ are the midpoints of $AD$ and $BC$ respectively. Prove that $\text{Area}(AND)+\text{Area}(BMC)=\text{Area}(ABCD)$.

---

My attempt:

Let $AN$ and $BM$ intersect at $E$, and let $DN$ and $CM$ intersect at $F$.

This is possible only if $\text{Area}(AEB)\text{Area}(CFD)=\text{Area}(MENF)$.

I am unable to go farther. I tried to construct diagonals and use the Midpoint Theorem, but it didn't work, and I can't find anywhere to use congruency or similarity.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Area}(ABN)+\text{Area}(CDN)
&={1\over2}BN\cdot AK+{1\over2}CN\cdot DL
\\&={1\over2}BN(AK+DL)
\\&=BN\cdot MH
\\&={1\over2}BC\cdot MH
\\&=\text{Area}(BCM).
\end{align}
$$

[image]

Comment: How do you $\Delta ABN$ to be $\frac12BN{}\cdot{}AH$? Shouldn't it be $AK$?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo, thank you. I'll correct in a minute.

Comment: Okay, now this answer is officially awesome. +1, and accepting soon if I don't get any more awesome answers.